# Midrashic sources regarding the Sea splitting into twelve paths

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, rashi, tehilim-psalms, yetziat-mitzrayim

Tehilim [136:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16357/showrashi/true#v13) says:

> לְגֹזֵר יַם סוּף לִגְזָרִים כִּי לְעוֹלָם חַסְדּוֹ
>
> To Him Who cut the Sea of Reeds asunder, for His kindness is eternal.

[Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi)'s commentary indicates that this is talking about God cutting twelve paths through the sea, one for each tribe. Does anyone know what Rashi's source in the [Midrash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrash) is, and where this idea shows up for the first time in the Midrash?

*This question was adapted from a Facebook post by [DovBear](http://dovbear.blogspot.com/).*

Comment: The Sfas Emes brings a medrash that thete was 600000 paths in the yam.

Comment: Fascinatingly, I once read in a goyishe non-fiction book that there is an American Indian tribe who have a tradition that many generations ago their ancestors were saved by their pursuing enemies by G-D having split a sea into twelve for them to escape through!

Answer (score 7):

[Pirkei d'Rebbi Eliezer ch. 42](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21858&pgnum=228) and Midrash Shocher Tov chapter 114,see also the Rav on Avos 5:3.

Answer (score 4):

Toras Shleimah ([15:127*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9751&st=&pgnum=135&hilite=)) brings the Midrash of the Yam Suf splitting into 12 lanes for the twelve tribes in the name of two of the "[smaller midrashim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smaller_midrashim)": [Midrash Vayosha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrash_Vayosha) ([Chapter 12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31535&st=&pgnum=22)) and [Midrash Temurah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrash_Temurah) ([Temurah 13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26827&st=&pgnum=100&hilite=)).

Answer (score 4):

See [Avot Derav Nattan 33:2](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/avot/33-2.htm) that cites the verse that you did. It also mentions other miracles that occurred at the sea.

Answer (score 3):

After [quoting the Mechilta on Beshalach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50393&pgnum=758) that says that the Sea was split into parts, [HaTorah HaTemimah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50393&pgnum=759) brings 3 sources that says it was split into 12:

- Midrash Shocher Tov 114
- Targum Yonatan (I'm assuming on Tehillim 136:13)
- [Rambam's Commentary on the Mishnayot, Avot 5:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&pgnum=380)

---

I wasn't able to find where the Midrash Shocher Tov mentions 12. (What I think is) the relevant passage starts on the bottom of [this page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14098&pgnum=164), but it does not bring a number.

The notes by MaHaR"i HaKohen do mention 12 parts. He says this could be hinted to by the fact that the verse says, "The water was **to them** as a wall". "to them" appears to be extra, but comes to teach us that each tribe had a wall, hence 12 parts.

Answer (score 3):

See both Targum Pseudo-Yonasan to [Shemos 14:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40279&st=&pgnum=148&hilite=) and in [Devarim 1:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40279&st=&pgnum=325&hilite=). The first one says that the waters "had twelve divisions according to the shevatim of yaacov" while the latter says that the crossing had a path "for each one of the shevatim."